# What items aren't safe to sell?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I've accumulated a lot of junk on my adventure already, and I've just met my first merchant. I'd like to sell, well, most of it. But while I'm quite comfortable selling all of these duplicate books and mediocre daggers, I'm not quite sure about some of these other items.

Often, in games of this sort, valuable non-usable items, such as gems or jewelry pieces end up being used in crafting systems or as turn ins. Is that true of any such items in BG3? I know most crafting systems weren't implemented during early access, so now that the game is live, I'm asking for up to date information that isn't based on that.

**What items should I make certain I don't sell to a merchant or drop?**

Comment: Quest items at least appear in a separate tab. So nothing essential can be lost. I see some of the tools in this question. Shovels are helpful, but do you need rope or hammers?

Answer (score 2):

Items with ***orange background color*** are often quest items/related important items, which you'll probably want to keep at least until you have finished the quest or crafting recipe they belong to. Once the quest is done you can go ahead and sell them, if the game even lets you sell them. Certain items can't be sold - you can tell which ones by right-clicking and trying to add them to "wares" in the inventory, if the game won't let you then it can't be sold.

(Note that legendary artifacts also have orange-like background color - actually yellow - but if you found one of those, you'll remember it.)

Same thing with keys, no point of saving them once you've unlocked all stuff in the area where the key was found. And keys seem kind of optional since some 99% of all locks are pickable and keys mainly serve the purpose to let one have a party without a rogue. (I have Astarion as pretty much permanent squad member and buffed his sleight of hand to the skies with artifacts, pretty much never need keys.)

The only thing I can come up with which you most definitely don't want to sell are  Illithid tadpoles (I'm not sure if they can be sold though?). You can't use them early but can do so later on, optionally.

Alchemy was introduced just now with the full release so I don't sell alchemy reagents either. Even if you don't plan to use the crafted potions, they sell for much more than the raw ingredients.

Comment: This answer is a good starting point, but I’d just like to point out to anyone reading while it’s the only answer that it’s far from complete. I’ve had a few unique non orange items called for in quests or to craft/combine already.

Comment: Not so much an orange background as an orange border. Magic items usually have a halo (their colour depending on the tier) as background.