# Filtering your inventory in Baldurs Gate 3 for sellable trash?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Baldurs Gate 3, in good old Divinity Original Sins manner, provides a world full of various items. Many of those things serve, essentially, for decoration/immersion in the game world but still can be looted and taken with you. Also the chests, barrels, boxes, sacks and fallen enemies you loot will carry a plethora of things, many of them are just random trash.

I realise that you can somehow flag items as "wares" to sell, but this is quite tedious. I might loot 10 items in a single room, I prefer not to manually click 3 times for each item to flag it.

- Is there any way to automatically filter your inventory to see only random trash, i.e. things that are not usable items, not used for crafting/as tools and not in quests?
- Or is there a "sell all trash" button/function hidden somewhere that I just haven't found yet?

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of [What items aren't safe to sell?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/403879/what-items-arent-safe-to-sell)

Answer (score 9):

You can select multiple items and right click to 'Add to wares' then when you visit a merchant or trade with an NPC, you can use Trade mode and click the 'Sell wares' button to sell them all.